# Would there be a physical Boundary Condition on Event Horizon for a perturbed Fluid of a Kerr-BH Accretion Disk?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, kerr-metric

Let's say we have a Steady-State Disk (Fishbone 1976 HD, or an MHD disk). For simplicity, we focus only on $\theta = \pi/2$.

> If we perturb every physical quantity by the rule $A = A+ \delta A $ (where $A= P,B,u,\rho,\rho_e$), could we possibly consider a boundary condition on event horizon, that will help us study the problem?  ($\delta A = 0$ for example or something like that, but with a reason behind it).